# custom dropdown not working well when I resize the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please can any one help me.
When I resize the browser then the collapse dropdown's backpart are shown what I dont want(problem 1.png).
 I want that when I will resize the browser the dropdown and it backpart will be hidden accroding to the header of dropdown.

when on hover, list item are not showing , i want to show images also on hover state.( problem 2png )

problem live link:
![enter image description here][1]http://tb.taslimk.tk/

Another problem:)

Comment: sorry 2png is not showing. please visit the live site example :  http://tb.taslimk.tk/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "style4.css" uses several media queries to change the size of the element (.cd-dropdown) that says "FILTER BY INTEREST".  Here's an example of one in there:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    .cd-dropdown > span {
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 4.2em;
    }
    .cd-dropdown ul li span {
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .cd-dropdown, .cd-select {
        width: 220px;
    }
}
```

Whereas the width of .cd-dropdown at full screen width I believe is 300px.

I think the issue is that the list element (ul, li), which is a child of .cd-dropdown, is not changing width as well whenever the media queries take charge.

I think the ul underneath .cd-dropdown only ever has a width of 100% set:

```
.cd-dropdown ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Maybe if you change the width of the ul to be the same px width as .cd-dropdown in every media query block, then this could solve your issue (the bug seems to revolve around the fact that the width of the ul is set to 100%).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky, but one way of handling this without having to modify the core dropdown library would be to add the following css rules to override the inline styles that get set by the library.

```
.cd-dropdown ul li {
    width: 100% !important;
    left: 0 !important;
}
```